# Pressing Esc when adding link also dismisses edit popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, popups, improve-edit

When you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> on an editor popup while in an edit dialog, the popup is closed.

Steps to reproduce:

- Find a post with a suggested edit
- Click the `edit(1)` link
- Click *Improve*
- Use the editor to add a link
- Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel adding a link
- The whole *Improve* dialog gets removed, including all of the changes I've made. It should only remove the dialog to add a link.

Obviously, the same thing happens when you upload an image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed as soon as the build rev `2013.11.12.1624` on meta and `2013.11.12.1145` on sites rolls out.